# Schedule Meeting for a Contact from Custom VF Page? Similar to Cloud Scheduler Functionality in Salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, scheduled-apex

Cloud scheduler in salesforce is used to schedule meetings for Contact, Leads or Account. Can the same functionality be achieved from Custom Visual force page. Either by invoking the same pop up screens or using apex code.

[image: Can "New Meeting Request" functionality be achieved using apex code?]

Can "New Meeting Request" functionality be achieved using apex code in custom VF Page?

On click of "New Meeting Request" button i get the following screens to schedule a meeting with that contact.

[image: Image2]

On clicking next i get the below screen-
 [image]

Can i invoke the same pop up screens from custom VF page? and if not can i do something from apex code like

```
Contact contact=[select FirstName,LastName from Contact where id=:contactid];
```

For this contact can i schedule a meeting using apex code itself?

Comment: Did you extract all of the code from the original source pages? I suspect the issue is that you'll need to make certain your code passes the ID of the contact to the next page in the pop-up. I've not attempted what you're doing, but that's what my instincts are telling me.

Comment: @crmprogdev From where can i extract the code for original source pages ?

Comment: Apologies for the delay in responding. There's a free app on the app exchange called Layout Page that will convert "most" any standard page into an editable visualforce page. My results with it have been fairly successful. There's only been a page or two that didn't convert for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that Meeting is also of type Event where a field called **GroupEventType** in the Event object distinguish between Event and Meeting.

**Unfortunately GroupEventType is read-only field, so i came to conclusion that i can't able to create meeting from apex code. If anyone of you have any other alternative method please do share here.**

I had created 2 Meetings and 1 Event for a contact then this is what i found when i exported the data to .csv using DataLoader.

[image: Image1]

And the documentation explaining that can be seen here -
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_event.htm
[image]

Comment: What you can't create through the API are "Proposed Events". The other two picklist values of "0" (Non-Group) and "1" (Group) are creatable. Once created, GroupEventType becomes Read Only.

Comment: If this is the answer, please mark it as such. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I added an answer to a similar question here that might help with what you're trying to do.

[Cloud Scheduler (Meeting Request)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/49315/cloud-scheduler-meeting-request/)