# Cloud Scheduler (Meeting Request)

Tags: apex, dynamic-visualforce, event

Can we pre populate To field in Meeting Request.How to achieve this.

or

Is there a way create a meeting request through apex/vf page

Note: This is the Pop-Up which comes when we click on **New Meeting Request** Button (Open Activities Related list) On Contact/Lead/Home Objects

[image: Meeting Request]

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this popup to show up in a Custom VF page by loading in this javascript resource

`<script src="/jslibrary/1413852410000/sfdc/Scheduling.js">`

Then to invoke the popup I ran this javascript code, merging in the correct contact Id.

`var contactId = '<<Current Contact Id>>';
navigateToUrl('javascript:void%28SchedulingProposeMeeting.openAskForMeetingDialog%28%27%2Fscheduling%2FcreateMeeting.apexp%3Fid%3D' + contactId + '%27%2C%20false%2C%20877%29%29%3B','RELATED_LIST','newproposemeeting');`

I'm sure this is absolutely not supported by Salesforce and could break with any update.

Comment: can you please post full vf page